# ZSH (oh-my-zsh) spaceship-theme not displaying normally in terminal (adds 3 dots ... to end)

Tags: command-line, zsh

I recently added zsh, oh-my-zsh and installed the [spaceship-zsh-theme](https://github.com/pascaldevink/spaceship-zsh-theme) which I have used on my mac for Ubuntu. I can see the font and style has changed, but for some reason, no matter what I do in Ubuntu there are always 3 dots `...` at the end of the title of a new line in the terminal.

Any clue why this is?

##### Ubuntu

```
~ …
➜
```

#### Mac

```
~
➜
```

### Resources

Relevant Github issue: https://github.com/spaceship-prompt/spaceship-prompt/issues/1193

Comment: Same issue.  I couldn't find out why. Did you happen to resolve this by any chance?

Comment: Not resolved I'm afraid. I figured I'd try a different terminal environment and see if, Kitty, or something handled it implicitly, but I haven't taken the time to experiment and try. Did @Buckshot-77's solution work for you?

Comment: I think it's a bug with the async feature. Check this [page](https://spaceship-prompt.sh/blog/2022-spaceship-v4/#asynchronous-rendering) they talk about the "..." placeholder. When I set `SPACESHIP_ASYNC_SYMBOL` with another symbol in the config file, I can confirm that it is the async symbol. So something is not working.

Comment: Try disabling async: `SPACESHIP_PROMPT_ASYNC=false`. This is the [github issue](https://github.com/spaceship-prompt/spaceship-prompt/issues/1193#issuecomment-1242036640).

Comment: @Michael you're write, that did get rid of the dots. I'm not sure what other functionality might be lost, but for the moment its an improvement over the eyesore.

Comment: When I disable async, it is super slow for me so not usable. I gave up and I am using the powerlevel10k theme instead.

Comment: @Michael, thanks for the updae. What specifically is really slow for you?

Comment: Just about anything, for example, waiting for the prompt to be ready to type in.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem here, and I solved it by installing the theme as a global npm dependency.

```
npm install -g spaceship-zsh-theme
```

Comment: hmmm I'll have to try that

Comment: Well I tried but it didn't quite work it seemed. I orginally installed by calling `git clone https://github.com/spaceship-prompt/spaceship-prompt.git "$ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/spaceship-prompt" --depth=1` and then setting symlink like: `ln -s "$ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/spaceship-prompt/spaceship.zsh-theme" "$ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/spaceship.zsh-theme"`

I then tried to use npm to install it, but the name is deprecated now to `spaceship-prompt`. While this didn't generate errors, on refreshing my terminal it can't find a reference to `spaceship-theme`.